# format datetime object inside ajax.actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a view where there are ajax.actionlinks, some of these action links need to display a date property of the model and I have the date property as follows:

```
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
```

however, because ajax.actionlink accepts a string for its first argument, I can't use a lambda expression :

```
m => m.Date
```

rather I'm using

```
Model.Date.ToString()
```

but this isn't showing the formatting I want. I've tried doing

```
Model.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
```

but I'm getting red underline because its not recognizing the ToString overload with 1 argument... any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Model.Date` is nullable, you need to access the `Value` of the `DateTime?` before  using that version of `ToString`:

```
Model.Date.HasValue ? Model.Date.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : null;
```